# VMWare VSphere to AWS Backup with Hypervisor Plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup, vmware-vcenter

Following along with this [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-backup-support-for-vmware-and-vmware-cloud-on-aws/), got the virtual machine up and hypervisor registered in AWS Backup console but when the backup runs I get a permissions error. When I try to run a on demand job it only let me use predefined AWSBackup roles.  The jobs fail almost instantly.

VSphere 6.7 storage is iScsi VMFS

Any ideas on how I can go about troubleshooting this, there's not a ton documentation ?

[image: Error]

Comment: I would be looking at the role doing the backup associated with AWS Backup, seeing if it has the right privileges. CloudTrail might tell you a little more. Service Control Policies should be considered.

Comment: Does anybody even use server fault anymore  ?

Comment: Yep. I'm not sure how many use VMWare on AWS though. Also, you didn't reply to my comment so the question looks abandoned. The error message along with my comment give you a way to look into this yourself.